# Заключается ли в кавычки название кафедр и факультетов?

Tags: кавычки, названия

Заключается ли в кавычки название кафедр и факультетов?

Задалась данным вопросом, зайдя на несколько сайтов, посвящённых поступлению абитуриентов в университеты, и посмотрев пару видео об этом.

Comment: Обычно без кавычек. Например, кафедра теории и практики перевода или кафедра фонетики английского языка. Направления или специальности - да, в кавычках (направление подготовки "общее языкознание").

Answer (score 2):

§ 193. Названия учреждений, учебных заведений и т. п., а также отделов и частей учреждений и организаций, не являющиеся собственными именами, пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: бюро обмена жилплощади, городское отделение связи, отдел кадров, сектор учёта, правление жилищно-строительного кооператива, районный совет народных депутатов, президиум, учёный совет, художественный совет, факультет журналистики, кафедра иностранных языков; то же при добавлении конкретизирующих цифр и слов: школа № 266, школа им. Маяковского, автобаза № 9, продовольственный магазин № 5, 12-я дивизия, колхоз им. Кирова. (Лопатин)

Найдено Поисковиком этого сайта.

10 июл '17 в 12:42

М_Г

(Собственные имена пишутся с прописной: кафедра «Архитектурно-строительные конструкции», факультет «Архитектурная реставрация».)